# Prevent jQuery Waypoints firing twice or multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to develop an infinite scroll with waypoints and a PHP MySQL ajax call, but each time the trigger comes into view, it strangely fires twice, so I get the same DB results appended twice, even though I refresh the waypoints after the ajax call was made.

The trigger button gets pushed down with more items being appended above it, so the waypoint should always be pushed down already, which it does, however it keeps firing twice each time.

How can I prevent this?

```
<div id="items-holder"></div>
<a href="#" id="load-more">Load More</a>

<script>
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
element: document.getElementById('load-more'),
offset: 'bottom-in-view',
handler: function() {
$.get('load-more-items.php', function(data) {
$('#items-holder').append(data);
if (data != ''){
Waypoint.refreshAll();
} // end if has data
}); // end ajax function
},
})
</script>
```

Comment: One year later, same problem here.